# Add User Data to Wiki Article

Tags: customization, acumatica, wiki, portal

I would like to place the users information into a Wiki Page so it is more personalized. I do know that the syntax to get this information is PXAccess.GetUserID(). How would this display into a Wiki Page?

Answer (score 1):

Acumatica does not suggest editing their built in Wiki articles for fear that should they update in a future version, you would either lose your edits, or would not get their updates.

Be that as it may, should you still want to attempt to change how the Wiki screens work - the Graph is WikiShowReader in PX.Data.dll, the ASPX and ASPX.cs files are in the Root/Wiki folder as ShowWiki.aspx, ShowWiki.aspx.cs
where Root is the root of the website.

You can likely use some JS, or the aspx.cs to find a token in the text and replace it.

IE
Write a method in a Graph Extension to return the name of the currently logged in User as a string, then in an event in the aspx.cs, call the method, find a specific substring of the content on string, and replace it with your desired string.